# Hyper Link Picture Not Working Right

Tags: php, html, css

I've been trying to work on this code for day's now and it's just not working right even though everything is right. Any help would be fantastic!

FYI : I'm trying to put a hover picture over a over one as a transparent, if you know what I mean!

Full code:

```
<br><div class="display1">
    <div class="display2">
        <div style="position:absolute; top:0px; background-image:url(http://www.unwritten-quotes.com/images/bgg.gif);background-repeat:repeat; background-color:transparent;" class="display3"></div>
        <div style="position:absolute; top:0px;"><a href="#" title="Testing" class="displayhover"><img src="http://www.unwritten-quotes.com/images/border.png" border="0"></a></div>
        <div class="displayquote">Testing</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="display1">
    <div class="display2">
        <div style="position:absolute; top:0px; background-image:url(http://www.unwritten-quotes.com/images/bgg.gif);background-repeat:repeat; background-color:transparent;" class="display3"></div>
        <div style="position:absolute; top:0px;"><a href="#" title="Testing" class="displayhover">
```

JSFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/za6n3/

Comment: Just post relevant code here.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed in your background image you do not have quotes around your link. I am not sure if this is the problem but if i copy your code into http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background-image_norepeat and put the link in for your image it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

put the background image and the overlay image in the same div

```
<div style="position:absolute; top:0px; 
    background:url(http://www.unwritten-quotes.com/images/bgg.gif)">
    <a href="http://adobe.com">
        <img src="http://www.unwritten-quotes.com/images/border.png" border="0">
    </a>
</div>
```

Edit: updated code to add `<a>` tag

Comment: That's actually what i want but with a hyper link so the user can click on the picture with a title on it above the main picture so the user will know what the name of the background is etc.   Like this http://i57.tinypic.com/217a1j.png

Comment: That's really easy, just wrap the image in an `<a>` tag. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thank you @Tim. Your a big help! It works great! All i need now is a title above the main overlay border like the picture above.

Comment: @TravisReed Glad to help. The title "Red Zebra" is part of the overlay PNG image. :) Please mark this as solved so it won't appear in the "unsolved" list. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hello Travis first off lets fix your code.

this is the code i made to fix yours, this is the first file index.php, this file will contain all of your HTML code, none of your CSS.

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /><meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en-US" />
    <title>...</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body id="body">
    <div id="body-container">
        <div id="display-1">
            <a class="display-2-btn" href="/">
                <img class="display-border" src="http://www.unwritten-quotes.com/images/border.png" width="" height="" alt="Testing" border="0" >
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

as you can tell we modified your code so that it will properly function, the first thing you can see that is different is the correct HTML structure,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

we added this for the simple purpose that any and all HTML document should have this, HTML documents that dont include its default structure usually do not function as they should, 
next we add this part of the code,

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /><meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en-US" />
    <title>...</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
```

we are looking at the meta tags, title tags, and link tag, we have the meta tags with the 
attribute http-equiv and inside http-equiv its says content-type and content-language this will tell your web server to tell the browser that you are using this code format for content-type and this is the default language for content-language, next is the title tag which tells the browser to put this as the title of the page e.g. the little title inside each tab, next is the link tag which links our CSS file to our main web page, when coding HTML or CSS it is always proper to put you HTML in one file and your CSS in its own file, it is not improper to put them together but is better practice to make a external stylesheet, only use the inline CSS if absolutely necessary, next we add to the body of our html document

```
<body id="body">
    <div id="body-container">
        <div id="display-1">
            <a class="display-2-btn" href="/">
                <img class="display-border" src="http://www.unwritten-quotes.com/images/border.png" width="" height="" alt="Testing" border="0" >
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

this is were we start to add the elements you see in your web browser, in the HTML language, the only thing outputted to the screen is inside the body, but external sheets or scripts are added in the head, scripts can be in the head or body, but any external link to files needs to be in the head of the document,

```
<div id="display-1">
    <a class="display-2-btn" href="/">
        <img class="display-border" src="http://www.unwritten-quotes.com/images/border.png" width="" height="" alt="Testing" border="0" >
    </a>
</div>
```

the first thing you see different in the body is that there is only display-1 there is no longer 2 display classes, and it is no longer a class but a id, we have also put our img tag in between the a tags, next we add our css file (Read me: the code below is its own file not stored in the index.php)

style.css

```
html{

}
body{
    background-color:#707070;
}
#body{

}   
#body-conainer{

}
#display-1{
    background-image:url('http://www.unwritten-quotes.com/images/bgg.gif');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:115px;
    height:139px;
    border-radius:20px;
}
.display-border{
    border-radius:20px;
}
```

the first thing we add to this code is the main structure e.g. what you see above, next we add this code to change the background color

```
body{
    background-color:#707070;
}
```

this makes the background color gray, next we add the background image,

```
#display-1{
    background-image:url('http://www.unwritten-quotes.com/images/bgg.gif');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:115px;
    height:139px;
    border-radius:20px;
}
```

this adds the background image and trims the image to fit the border, next we trim the border added within the HTML code

```
<img class="display-border" src="http://www.unwritten-quotes.com/images/border.png" width="" height="" alt="Testing" border="0" >
```

we use this code to trim the border,

```
.display-border{
    border-radius:20px;
}
```

and there you have it a fully working copy of what i think you wanted, let me now if this was or was not what you were looking for, i also highly recommend that you learn the HTML and CSS syntax a little better before diving straight in,

here is a good place to start with html and css:

http://www.w3schools.com/

here is a good place to start with php:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/

i hoped this helped you out (=